# compatibility between ios 4.x and 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I develop with xcode 4.1 and I'm testing my app with the iphone simulator 4.3. My application will work on ios 5 ? should i update to xcode 4.2 , I have not completed my application if I do the update now, I risk nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application will work on iOS 5 but is hightly recommended to update your Xcode to 4.2 with all the iOS 5 sdk and new API's.

Comment: to update xcode from 4.1 to 4.2 ,I must re-download from appstore? i can't run update think on xcode 4.1 ?

Answer (score 1):

You should also test on iOS 5 if possible. Normally an app will run fine on iOS 5 even if it's built for iOS 4. It's your call on updating to the new Xcode–or if you even want to build or iOS 4.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to test on iOS 5 in order to see whether works correctly. Generally an app will be compatible with a new version of iOS, but it might get some new bugs, this will depend on the APIs and libraries you used. You cannot say whether an app will run perfect on iOS 5. Therefore an upgrade to Xcode 4.2 is inevitable in order to correctly test your app on iOS 5.

Comment: I'm unaware of forward-compatibility ever being an issue for compiled code.